# Switching from md5 to password_hash

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using md5 for password. e.g `$password=md5($_POST['password']);;`
I have heard md5 is only partially secure. now i want to use `password_hash` function `$password=password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Here is my code:

```
    if($submit)
    {
        $first=$_POST['first'];
        $password=password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");
        $sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $first . "' and password = '". $password . "'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $result=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($result>0)
{

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    header("Location:loginhome.php");

}
}
```

Now How should i store my password in database. previously while using md5 there was a md5 in function field. now what?

Comment: I think varchar(255) is a good solution

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php it's all in there.

Comment: 1. Read the manual. 2. Use prepared statements. 3. To validate passwords, see point 1 (hint: `password_verify()` function)

Comment: There is a pretty good walk-through [here](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html). The field in your database should be a `TEXT` type, to allow for different algorithms which may be added to `password_hash()`. As it stands now, the hash is 60 characters in length *and will become longer*.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual next time ;) You need to use `password_hash()` when storing a password (eg on signup or password change), and when you need to check the password (eg on login) then you grab the already-hashed password from the database THEN call `password_verify()` with the user password and the hashed password from the database like so:

`password_verify($cleartextUserPassword, $hashedPasswordFromDatabase);`

If `password_verify()` returns true, let them in!