# Password is not verified using function password_verify

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, passwords

I think i have hashed password using function `PASSWORD` directly from mysql database(am i doing wrong here?). And i am trying to verify that password with this code:

```
    if($submit)
    {
        $first=$_POST['first'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $hash="*85955899FF0A8CDC2CC36745267ABA38EAD1D28"; //this is the hashed password i got by using function PASSWORD in database
        $password=password_verify($password,$hash);
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");
        $sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $first . "' and password = '". $password . "'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $result=mysqli_num_rows($result);


        if($result>0)
    {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        header("Location:loginhome.php");

    }
}
```

But the password is not matching. What am i missing here?

**UPDATE**:

After all the suggestions i have used `password_hash` from php code to store into database.

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");
$password=password_hash('ChRisJoRdAn123',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql="INSERT INTO admin (username,password)values('ChrisJordan','$password')";
$db->query($sql);
```

still the password is not matching.

Comment: `password_verify` does not use the MySQL password format (it uses Bcrypt).

Comment: Are you using mysql `PASSWORD` function?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i don't see Bcrypt function in mysql itself.

Comment: @micky I mean PHP's `password_*` function use Bcrypt, MySQL uses something else.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara see my updates in question please.

Comment: You should also show the updated code you are using to verify the password.

Comment: @jbafford only the $hash='$2y$10$jhBhI/A1rpi.j6zYAX.uLemkmg9uPsfaaq6/Xa1LADr...'; is changed others are same.

Comment: That's not the way you use password_verify. Please see the examples in the php documentation.

Comment: @jbafford it is similar way there.

Comment: _I feel nobody has put this in plain simple English, so I will:_ You cannot hash a password using MYSQL's `PASSWORD()` function and expect PHP to verify it using `password_verify()` **They are 2 totally different animals** You must use `password_hash()` in conjunction with `password_verify()` _PHP is clever but its not magic_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot search for a salted password hash in a database. To calculate the hash you need the password_hash() function as you already did correctly in your insert statement.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

To check a password, you first need to search by username only (used a prepared query to avoid sql injection):

```
$sql = 'select * from admin where username = ?';
$db->prepare($sql);
$db->bind_param('s', $first);
```

When you finally got the stored hash from the database, it can be checked like this:

```
// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net/password_hash) to encode passwords verified with [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

The MySQL function [`PASSWORD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) is something entirely different. It is used for encoding passwords specific to MySQL authentication. (MySQL specifically recommends against using `PASSWORD` for anything *other* than MySQL authentication.)

The two use different hashing algorithms, present their output in different formats, and are generally not compatible with each other.

---

The typical way to use `password_hash` and `password_verify` is:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//Store $hash in your database as the user's password

//To verify:
//Retrieve $hash from the database, given a username
$valid = password_validate($password, $hash);
```

The problem in your code is that you're doing this:

> ```
> $password=password_verify($password,$hash);
> $sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $first . "' and password = '". $password . "'";
> ```

`password_verify` returns a boolean (whether the password and hash matched). Instead, you need to retrieve the hash from the database and match the entered password with that hash.

Comment: How could i use password_hash from mysql. i have used this: insert into admin(username,password)values('ChrisJordan','password_hash(ChRiSjoRdaN123,PASSWORD_DEFAULT) but failed. you know the syntax error.

Comment: `password_hash` is a PHP function. You must call it from PHP code. MySQL doesn't know anything about it.

Comment: now i have used password_hash in php code. please see my updates in question.

Answer (score 1):

`password_verify` is a boolean function which return either `true` or `false`. In your code, after getting value of password from Post param, you doing this operation

```
$password=password_verify($password,$hash);
```

which changes the `$password` value to `true` or `false` and that boolean value stored in `$password` you are using in mysql select statement

```
$sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $first . "' and password = '". $password . "'";
```

**Another thing** is it might be possible that the hashed/salted password you are using is not the correct hashed value of the password you are using.

---

**Update:** Try this

```
$cost = [
    'cost' => 15,
];

$hash_password = password_hash('ChRisJoRdAn123', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $cost);
```

before any db operation, change your `password` field `varchar` length to >=`64`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin (username,password)values('ChrisJordan','".$hash_password."')";
```

After insert operation, execute the select statement with the user

```
$sql = "select * from admin where username = 'ChrisJordan'";
```

after this fetching `hased password` and `password` from the **post parameter**, you will need to verify both passwords using `password_verify`

```
if (password_verify(validate($_POST['password']), $hash_password_from_db)) {
    echo "Valid Password";
}else{
    echo "Invalid Password";    
}
```

Comment: It displays undefined function validate().

Comment: you need to validate the input... I just used the dummy function.

Comment: @martinstoeckli select query will return the record of username 'ChrisJordan' and in that record we need to fetch the hasedpassword and use the same in `password_verify`

Comment: @Haridarshan - Oh sorry, i was misleaded by the first statement, where the password is still part of the query. BTW a cost factor of 15 may be a bit high.

Comment: @Haridarshan - What is the function `validate()` for? It shouldn't be there, password_verify() will check the password on its own.

Comment: @martinstoeckli validate function is just to sanitize the post parameter and yeah cost 15 is very high just for security  reason. When more security is needed cost should be high

Comment: @Haridarshan - But the validate function cannot return 2 parameters as is required by the verify function, the paranthesis are probably wrong. A work factor of 15 is about 32 times the default hashing time, so better you have a fast server then...

Comment: @martinstoeckli sorry, my mistake i forgot to add the closing parenthesis for validate method.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Seeing that this question has yet to contain a green tick next to any of the answers, am submitting the following in order to point out probable issues.

I noticed that you are trying to move over from MD5 to `password_hash()` - `password_verify()`.

- Your other question [Switching from md5 to password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134769/switching-from-md5-to-password-hash)

What you need to know is that MD5 produces a 32 character length string, as opposed to `password_hash()` being a 60 length.

- Use `varchar(255)`.

If you kept your password column's length to 32, then you will need to clear out your existing hashes from that column, then ALTER your column to be 60, or 255 as the manual suggests you do.

You will need to clear out all your existing passwords, ALTER your column, create a new hash, then try your login code again.

I see this in your code:

```
"*85955899FF0A8CDC2CC36745267ABA38EAD1D28"; //this is the hashed password i got by using function PASSWORD in database
```

This string `*85955899FF0A8CDC2CC36745267ABA38EAD1D28` is 40 long, which is too short and has been cut off.

This tells me that your column's length is 40, instead of 60, or again as the manual suggests, 255.

MD5 reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

> Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.

Reference for `password_hash()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE on failure.

To ALTER your column, here is a reference link:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Also make sure that your form contains a POST method and that the inputs bear the matching name attributes and that no whitespace gets introduced.

You can use `trim()` to get rid of those.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()`.

---

**Edit:**

What you need to do is fetch an array and get the match on that.

```
$sql = "select * from admin where username = '".$first."' and password = '".$password."' ";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
     $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            //Password matches, so create the session
            // $_SESSION['user']['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            // header("Location:/members");

        echo "Match";


        }else{
            echo  "The username or password do not match";
        }
}
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
$query = "SELECT * from admin WHERE username='$first'";

$result = $db->query($query);

if($result->num_rows ===1){
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

    echo "match";
} else {
$error = "email or Password is invalid";
echo $error;
}

}
mysqli_close($db); // Closing Connection
```

Comment: but my password column is varchar with length 255 characters and still the password is cut-off and shown ... at the end.

Comment: @micky seeing your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35156137/ you're using `TEXT`, use `VARCHAR`. Look at this about TEXT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html *If a TEXT column is indexed, index entry comparisons are space-padded at the end.*

Comment: someone suggested me to use TEXT. failed either way.

Comment: @micky either way, you probably can't go changing your column type from TEXT to VARCHAR, as this may have some adverse effects and may have to create new hashes again.

Comment: @micky give me a minute, I think I know what else is wrong.

Comment: @micky Reload my answer and look near the end under **Edit:**.

Comment: @micky and reload again under **Another possible solution:**. If that doesn't work, then something else is failing you. There's really nothing else I can say/do to help.

Comment: @micky You're welcome. You need to start over then. There are too many unknowns at this point. If your form also contains a POST method, if name attributes are correct, if whitespace is introduced during the hash insert.... what I posted as edits were taken from my own personal libraries and can't see how it would fail. Good luck, I wish you well. *Cheers*

Comment: Now worked. followed this 'To check a password, you first need to search by username only.' sentence suggested.

Comment: @micky which is what I wrote here `$query = "SELECT * from admin WHERE username='$first'";` - what am I not grasping? I knew that's what it was, which is why I gave you another piece of code. oh well, it works.

Comment: @micky what I don't get though is that my `$query = "SELECT * from admin WHERE username='$first'";` is what most likely set you off to accept the other answer. They wrote you a prepared statement `select * from admin where username = ?` and does the same thing as my additional solution, it checks against the username, but does not query the row. You can keep the accepted answer, I've no problem with that, but that answer should have been accepted 5 hours ago, and would have avoided my doing all this work for nothing. I'm a little ticked, TBH. But at the same time glad it was finally resolved.

Comment: i very much appreciate your efforts. And i am not using prepared statements(i should) as suggested. the reason for accepting that answer is that 'sentence' was in my mind before you wrote that last code.and the reason for not accepting 5 hours ago, you know the TEXT-VARCHAR problem i recreated the table. thanks.

Comment: @micky You're welcome Micky. Yes, you should be using a prepared statement. I also did think that you may have had to rebuild/recreate the table as it may have gotten corrupted. *Cheers*